# Python: Modifying a Function to Search Values in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote a simple function that receives a dictionary and a string as a parameter. The function uses the string to search the dictionary and then returns a new dictionary with results.

Now i need some help modifying this code, or creating a new function, that when passed a string, searches values, in the `key:value` pair, as opposed to only the keys. So if I pass '1' as a parameter I get a new dictionary which includes cat.

Hopefully this is clear. Thanks in advance.

```
a = {'rainbows': 'xbox', 'solider': 'miltary', 'cat': 1}

def searchKeys(aDictionary,searchTerm):
    results = {}

    for i in aDictionary:
        if searchTerm in i:
            results[i] = aDictionary[i]
    return results

###searchKeys(a,'r') -> {'rainbows': 'xbox', 'solider': 'miltary'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once you have a key `i`, the value for that key is `aDictionary[i]`, so just extend your testing.

There are more optimal ways of doing this, that don't do the look-up as explicitly, but the above is straight-forward and easy to understand, and should be fine for many cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
def searchKeys(aDictionary,searchTerm):
    results = {}

    for k,v in aDictionary.iteritems():
        if searchTerm in k or searchTerm in v:
            results[k] = v
    return results
```

or shorter:

```
results = dict((k,v) for k,v in a.iteritems() if searchItem in k or searchItem in v)
```

It will however not work with your example dictionary, because `1` (value for `cat`) is not a string and therefore cannot *contain* another string.

Comment: this would work but my solution must be coded using python 3.2. and i think the .iteritems() method was deprecated.

Comment: @mysticxhobo, then use `.items()` simply.

Answer (score 1):

With Python 2.7, this is the most simple solution:

```
def searchItems(aDictionary, searchTerm):
    return {k:v for k, v in aDictionary.iteritems()
        if searchTerm in k or searchTerm in str(v)}
```

Or, if you are sure that all values are strings, you can just write `in v` instead of `in str(v)`.